# nodejs install iconv error on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Hi i have issues install iconv for nodejs. I already installed nodejs-legacy and the error message doesn't seems tell any error because the node -e "require('nan')" totally working fine but still node-gyp still fails. I have a couple of libssl.so file version missing but I doubt it related with the node-gyp issue. Any ideas why it happens ?

```
[12:15:41 qiong-h8-1234]% which -a node                                                                        /usr/include/nodejs
/usr/bin/node

[12:18:13 qiong-h8-1234]% sudo npm install -g iconv                                                            /usr/include/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> iconv@2.1.5 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iconv
> node-gyp rebuild

nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
nodejs: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by nodejs)
node dir/usr/include/nodejs
node: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:432:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! iconv@2.1.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.1.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the iconv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "iconv"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/include/nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/include/nodejs/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/node -v` show? I'm guessing it might be the amateur radio-related node program from Debian/Ubuntu and not node.js.

Comment: it seems it shows correct version. `[12:23:37 qiong-h8-1234] /usr/bin/node -v                                                                     
v0.10.15`

Comment: Well, as far as the "no version information available" errors go, that's happening because the version of the libcrypto/libssl libraries that node from the `nodejs` package was compiled against, do not match what is currently being used. Is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set in your environment? Did you install OpenSSL from the same source as node?

Comment: thx. seems the ssl library problem. For some reason, there is libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib that's different from the ones are used by current version of node.  (i forgot how these files are placed into the directory). after i renamed the file, the errors are gone.